# passing the Jacobian to newton_krylov nonlinear solver in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I want to solve a nonlinear system of algebraic equations by using newton_krylov solver in python.

The function defining the system of equations looks like:

```
def sys(x, param1, param2, param3, param4):
    
    ...
    
    return f
```

It gets a vector `x` at the input, together with three vectors `param1`, `param2`, `param3` and one number `param4`, that serve as parameters, and it returns another vector `f` at the output.
I have also a function that gives the Jacobian of the system; it looks like

```
def jac(x, param1, param2, param3):
    
    dim, =x.shape  # this is the first line of this function that appears to be problematic
    ...
    
    return jacob
```

This function takes at input a vector `x`, together with the same parameters as `sys` a part from `param4`, and it returns another vector `jacob`.

Finally the solver is called as following

```
sol=newton_krylov(lambda x:sys(x, param1, param2, param3, param4),guess,method=jac(x, param1, param2, param3))
```

At this point I get an error message at the line `dim, =x.shape` in the `jac` function that reads: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1).

I believe that the solver does not understand that `x` in `method=jac(x, param1, param2, param3)` is the vector of unknowns variables, but I do not know how to solve this problem.

A big thanks to anyone who might have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The vector `x` has shape `(n,1)` where n is the number of values in the vector. Because of this, `x.shape` returns `(n,1)`, but you are expecting it to return `(n,)`. A solution is to capture the `1`, but not store it. i.e.

```
dim,_ = x.shape
```

Comment: Thank you Lisa, your suggestion helped to correct the mistake I did, however I get now another error message: 
```
 method=jac(x, param1, param2, param3))

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```
It looks like the solver does not recognize the `x` in `jac` as the same `x` in `sys`

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, this sounds like a separate problem. You might consider opening a new question for it. Please upvote and accept my answer if it solved your current problem, thanks!

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I have not enough reputation.