# passing the Jacobian to newton_krylov nonlinear solver in python: part 2

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

This question is connected to the same problem as in [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665632/passing-the-jacobian-to-newton-krylov-nonlinear-solver-in-python). I copy-paste here the main body:

I want to solve a nonlinear system of algebraic equations by using newton_krylov solver in python.

The function defining the system of equations looks like:

```
def sys(x, param1, param2, param3, param4):
    
    ...
    
    return f
```

It gets a vector `x` at the input, together with three vectors `param1`, `param2`, `param3` and one number `param4`, that serve as parameters, and it returns another vector `f` at the output.
I have also a function that gives the Jacobian of the system; it looks like

```
def jac(x, param1, param2, param3):
    
    ...
    
    return jacob
```

This function takes at input a vector `x`, together with the same parameters as `sys` a part from `param4`, and it returns another vector `jacob`.

Finally the solver is called as following

```
sol=newton_krylov(lambda x:sys(x, param1, param2, param3, param4),guess,method=jac(x, param1, param2, param3))
```

**Question:**
I would like to understand what is the correct way to pass the external `jac`. With the actual syntax, it seems that the solver does not understand that `x` in `method=jac(x, param1, param2, param3)` is the vector of unknowns variables.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your solver call and the documentation in a similar solver, [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html), I would try changing

`method=jac(x, param1, param2, param3)`

to

`method=lambda x: jac(x, param1, param2, param3)`.

This wraps `jac(x, *params)` in the same way as you have already done for `sys`, resulting in a callable `jac(x)` being passed to `newton_krylov`. Otherwise, Python will try to evaluate `jac(x, *params)` and then pass the result to `method` (in the process searching for a potentially undefined variable `x` and raising a `NameError` if it can't find it).